# Implement html output for a model field in Django

Tags: python, django

I've another quick question, I need to use very often a specific html representation for a model field. I know there is a lot of documentation for forms but what about simple model field ?  For instance :

models.py

```
class Status (models.Model):
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Order'))
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Name'), max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    color = models.CharField(_(u'Color'), max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
```

template.html

```
{{status.order.as_span}} will be equivalent to <span>{{status.order}}<span>
```

The first idea I have is to implement a function inside a manager but seems to break the MVC rules ... There is a proper way for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't assemble html in your view code, this is what template tags are for. Put this in eg. `<app>/templatetags/<app>tags.py` (replace `<app>` with your app name):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def spanme(fld):
    return mark_safe("<span>%s</span>" % fld)
```

and use it as:

```
{% load <app>tags %}
...
{% spanme status.order %}
```

Comment: That's way too convoluted for such a simple use case.

Comment: Absolutely not. As the OP said he would be needing this for "every PositiveIntegerField in each of my models", this seems like the only sensible solution. (1) it keeps presentation logic out of the models, (2) it collects this functionality in one place, and (3) it really is quite simple and assuming you have other template tags and filters it's almost trivially simple.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was a bit busy.. Seems to work fine ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to subclass the model field also:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.db import models


class SpanValue(unicode):
    def as_span(self):
        return mark_safe(u"<span>%s</span>" % self)


class SpanField(CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return SpanValue(value)


class SpanModel(models.Model):
    foo = SpanField(max_length=25)
```

then you could use it like this:

```
from django import template
from maint.models import *

#val = SpanModel.objects.create(foo='bar')
val = SpanModel.objects.get(foo='bar')  # must get it from the db for `to_python` to run

t = template.Template(u"""{{ val.foo.as_span }}""")
print t.render(template.Context({'val': val}))
```

which would print

```
<span>bar</span>
```

Doing something like this would be very surprising to anyone else, so please never ever do this :-)

ps: if you inherit from something that isn't a text field you might be able to override `__unicode__` (so you wouldn't have to use `.as_span` in the template), however that is considerably more work.